# NoMethodError in Views of a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, partials

I am following a tutorial where I have to make a sort of directory website. Because of the need to have a page where a user can write a review, I create the views and the form for the reviews. The steps I have done were:

1 - Created a reviews folder at app/views/reviews:

2 - Created inside that folder a partial called _forms.html.erb for the reviews

```
 <%= simple_form_for(@review) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :content, required: true %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :place_id, required: true, value: @place_id %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
 <% end %>
```

3 - To render the review/_form on the places/show I add:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
    <h3>Reviews by People</h3>
    <%= render 'reviews/form' %>
  </div>
```

Got an error when trying to render the form so I went to PlacesController and I put the following line of code on the show method:

```
  # GET /places/1
  # GET /places/1.json
  def show
    @review = Review.new 
  end
```

My routes.rb file has got the routes for the reviews. The error I got was:

```
NoMethodError in Places#show
Showing C:/workinrails/myyelpapp/app/views/reviews/_form.html.erb where line #5 raised:
undefined method `content' for #<Review:0x9200a30>
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/places/show.html.erb

app/views/reviews/_form.html.erb:5:in `block in _app_views_reviews__form_html_erb___988880813_76383660'
app/views/reviews/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_reviews__form_html_erb___988880813_76383660'
app/views/places/show.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_places_show_html_erb__530556826_71913768'
```

I can provide any code snippets for a better understanding

Comment: A little confusion in your names here. Pages vs Places. Do you perhaps have both PagesController and PlacesController and forgot to add show action in correct PlacesController

Comment: I corrected that info on the question, thanks. I have a PagesController and a PlacesController. On my PagesController there's just the def home method with nothing inside. In my PlacesController in the show action I have this: @review = Review.new

Comment: What are the columns in Review table.

Comment: @rohan can you paste the fields in your Review table?

Comment: @rohan I have "place_id", "user_id" and "context" at the reviews table.

Comment: `content` or `context`?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma that was it, typewriting mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new column called content on reviews table

```
bundle exec rails g migration add_content_to_reviews content:string

bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a specified column name in your table

> rails g migration AddColumnNameToTableName column_name:datatype

then

> rails db:migrate

**Note:-**
You should know the difference b/w form_for & form_tag,

*form_for*

Your using here form_for, so you should specify only in you have already created  DB column name

*form_tag*

form_tag you don't need to sapecify required column name, you can use any name, you will get params of that value in your controller